# How to know a complex function is analytic without going to the whole process of checking Cauchy-Riemann condition?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration, cauchy-riemann-equations

How to know a function like for example $f(z)=\frac{1}{z}$ is analytic without turning it into $\frac{x-iy}{x^2+y^2}$ and then taking the partial and stuff?

Comment: In this case, you can just mimic the direct proof that $1/x$ real-differentiable to show directly that $1/z$ is complex differentiable.

Comment: Show that for $z_0 \ne 0$ we have: $ \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0} = -\frac{1}{zz_0} \to  -\frac{1}{z_0^2}$ as $z \to z_0.$